# Node.js + socket.io conection_refused error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Hy guys, I have this error which really killing me. I ma creating a little game with node.js and socket.io and I have a lot of connection all around and from time to time I am getting this error which really hard to get rid of. Any help would be great !!

[image]

In general this error can occur on random basis. I could be fixing some css and it could appear. I am really lost now.

app.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

var mysql = require("mysql");

/* Creating POOL MySQL connection.*/
var pool    =   mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit      :   100,
    host              :   'localhost',
    user              :   'root',
    password          :   '',
    database          :   'game',
    debug            :   false
});

app.listen(3005);

var socketCount = 0;
var socketHeroes = new Array(); // socket.id => hero_id
var socketid_byhero = new Array(); // hero_id => socket.id

io.on('connection',function(socket){
});
```

script.js

```
var socket = io.connect(":3005", {
    'connect timeout': 30,
    'reconnect': true,
    'reconnection delay': 2000,
    'max reconnection attempts': 10000,
    'force new connection':true,
    'query': "hero_hash="+ hero_login_hash
});
```

Comment: Add relevant code : Client side+Server side >> then , we can assess

Comment: Everything else are just a bunch of functions. And thx for replying !